# drawing plot lines on QGraphicsScene

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem

I designed a QGraphicsScene like a graph with scale at both axis and with the data i able to plot points on the the scene using QGraphicsItem.
but I don’t know which method will be suitable for connecting the points so it can be look like a graph plotted.
PainterPath or some other specific things ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say [QPainter::drawPolyline()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qpainter.html#drawPolyline-3) is a good option (or [QPainterPath::addPolygon](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/qpainterpath.html#id-952c30ae-8f22-40dd-b648-b920716eeec3)). You can use [QPolygonF](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qpolygonf.html) to contain your points. Then you just pass this to the QPainter's `drawPolyline` function.

```
QPolygonF polyline;   
polyline.append(QPointF(x, y)); // add your points
painter->drawPolyline(polyline);
```

or

```
QPainterPath painterPath;
painterPath.addPolygon(polyline);
```

Comment: I will do the same and reply you. but how i can highlight the points . i think with the same points QPointF(x,y) i can position some other item on top of the line. ex: ellipseItem on each point ..? or some other way is there also ..?

Comment: @Wagmare I think you will have to add ellipses to highlight the points. You can do it either with [QPainter::drawEllipse](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qpainter.html#drawEllipse-5) or [QPainterPath::addEllipse](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qpainterpath.html#addEllipse-3).